# How to call a new intent from SetOnItemClickListener of an Adapter in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, adapter

Below is the code for a listview with an adapter

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_users);
    final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewusers);
    //onlineUsers.setAdapter()

    //final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String username = intent.getStringExtra(connection.SERVER_ONLINE_USERS);

    String[] values = username.split(",");

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

       // view.setAlpha(1);

      }


    });

  }
```

What i want to do is get the String item which will be clicked on in the listview, start a new intent and pass the string item to it,

something similar to:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, activity.class);
sign.putExtra(KEY, value);
startActivity(i);
```

But when I use the above `Intent` code in my `onItemClickListener()` I get an error.

```
"The Constructor Intent(New AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<activity>) is undefined"
```

The suggested way to fix it is to remove the arguments from the intent and have it like this

```
Intent i = new Intent();
```

Comment: The problem is that you haven't told us what the problem is

Comment: once i click something on the listview, it will be saved in final String item, i want to add this string to a bundle and start a new activity

Comment: so what's the problem of replacing your intent code inside onItemClick() of setOnItemClickListener()?

Comment: sorry if i didnt state the problem clear, when i write this, i get an error with the suggested way to fix it is to remove the arguments from the intent and have it like this Intent i = new Intent(); "The Constructor Intent(New AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<activity>) is undefined"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm confused on the problem because you seem to know how to do it. So let's put it together

```
 @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
      int position, long id) {
    final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

   // view.setAlpha(1);

   Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), activity.class);  // get a valid context
   i.putExtra("someKey", item);  //I don't know where sign came from
   startActivity(i);

  }
```

then get it in your `Activity` such as in `onCreate()` with

```
Intent itent = getIntent();
String value = intent.getStringExtra("someKey");
```

Comment: sorry if i didnt state the problem clear, when i write this, i get an error with the suggested way to fix it is to remove the arguments from the intent and have it like this
Intent i = new Intent();

"The Constructor Intent(New AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<activity>) is undefined"

Comment: That information would have been **very** valuable from the beginning though I suspected as much. Look at my answer again. You weren't using a valid `Context`

Comment: You're welcome. No problem, just try to remember for next time that we typically don't know the problem you are having if you don't tell us. Often it can be many possibilities. After writing, read through the question as if you have never seen the code before...that should help.